# eglot + gopls (golang) , make 'find definition' work under /usr/local/src/go

Tags: golang, eglot

Eglot + gopls works fine.

I have the following in my init.el, and it works for installed packages ([mod files](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/emacs.md#configuring-project-for-go-modules-in-emacs))

```
(require 'project)

(defun project-find-go-module (dir)
  (when-let ((root (locate-dominating-file dir "go.mod")))
    (cons 'go-module root)))

(cl-defmethod project-root ((project (head go-module)))
  (cdr project))

(add-hook 'project-find-functions #'project-find-go-module)
```

But when I end up visiting a file under `/usr/local/go/src/`
none of `find-definition, find-references` works.

Is there a way to make them work when you are outside of your project?